# Logback placeholders not working with tests

Tags: java, logging, slf4j, logback

I have code with lines of logs, which looked like:

```
log.info("Message received with ID :"+ messageId);
```

I need change all concat to logback-style with placeholders.

```
log.info("Message received with ID :{}", messageId);
```

It works fine, when I see logs they are OK. I also have tests based on logging, I write expectation messages, then send message it passes through logic and I check, if logs are the same as expected. http://www.infoq.com/articles/Utilizing-Logging. When I had concat style logs, everythings was good, but now I don't see values, I see brackets {} in this tests, and they all fail.
so, application gives me:

```
Message received with ID : 32145
```

but tests give me:

```
Message received with ID :{}
```

Does anyone have the same problem and how it could be fixed? Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Are you 100% sure your `log` variable is of `org.slf4j.Logger` type in all cases? BTW this is an SLF4J feature, not Logback.

Comment: private static org.slf4j.Logger log = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger("DevUpdLogger");  Yess, slf4j  100% sure. I forgot to tell, I have multiple binding problem, could it be problem?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is most likely an implementation issue in TestLoggingAppender mentioned in the [InfoQ article](http://www.infoq.com/articles/Utilizing-Logging). The article mentions its implementation of the `doAppend` method:

```
public synchronized void doAppend(LoggingEvent loggingEvent) {
  String msg = **loggingEvent.getMessage()**.toString();
}
```

In logback-classic, the [ILoggingEvent](http://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/classic/spi/ILoggingEvent.html).getMessage() method returns the raw (unformatted) message. You need to call [getFormattedMessage()](http://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/classic/spi/ILoggingEvent.html#getFormattedMessage%28%29) to retrieve the formatted message.

Answer (score 1):

You should try `new Object[]{messageId}` as method paramether instead of `messageId`.
To be more precise:

```
log.info("Message received with ID :{}", new Object[]{messageId});
```

Comment: Passing new Object[]{..} as a first parameter is unlikely to help.